# Why does the events I created with Laravel have the 'App\Events' appended in the beginning?

Tags: laravel, events, listener, laravel-5.4, broadcasting

I created events using Laravel and am utilizing it in conjunction with Pusher. On my Pusher Debug Console, every time I fire off a event from my Laravel application, it shows up as 'App\Events\testEvent', whereas I need it to show up as just 'testEvent' like it does when I fire off a dummy event using the tool in the Pusher Debug Console.

https://www.screencast.com/t/cxQ30SZh5x

How do I type the code into my Laravel application so that it fires off the event as 'testEvent' instead of 'App\Events\testEvent'?

To fire the event, I am just using web.php in routes folder as follows:

```
Route::get('/testEvent', function() {
  event(new testEvent());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may customize the event name that gets broadcasted using the `broadcastAs` function on your Event class.

See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/broadcasting#broadcast-name

```
public function broadcastAs()
{
    return 'testEvent';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is the namespace the event classes are created under. Look at the top of your event files and you will see `namespace App\Events;`

Remove the namespace if you don't need it there, although why do you need it removed? I suspect there is another issue. Laravel events and Pusher have been working well together for quite some time.